# How to merge two or more arrays that have the key difference is equal to 1 or equal to 2 with PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
$array1 =array(
         '1' => array(
                  'a' => 'value 1a'
                ),
         '2' => array(
                  'b' => 'value 2b'
                ),
         '4' => array(
                  'c' => 'value 4a'
                ),
         '9' => array(
                  'd' => 'value 9c'
                ),
         '12' => array(
                  'e' => 'value 12e'
                )
);
```

I just wanted to combine an array that contains only key difference is less than or equal to 2

array key example:

```
2-1 =1 **OK**
4-2 =2 **OK**
9-2 =7 **NOT OK**
12-9 =3 **NOT OK**
```

The final result ($array2 from $array1) will look like:

```
$array2 =array(
           '1' =>array(
                  'a' => 'value 1a',
                  'b' => 'value 2b',
                  'c' => 'value 4c'
                ),
           '9' => array(
                  'd' => 'value 9c'
                ),
           '12' => array(
                  'e' => 'value 12e'
                );
```

I have tried to do some methods but still not successful ..
how to do it with php or using php arrays function may be easier ??

*Thank you for your help...*

Comment: first i think `9-2 =7 **NOT OK**` will be `9-4=5**NOT OK**` and what you have tried so for?

Comment: 1) `9-2 =7` doesn't seem to match the other pattern 2) Your OK and NOT OK doesn't match with what your expected output is. 3) And the most important question: What exactly you want to do?! The only thing I get is, if the next array key is <= 2 than the previous one keep it or something like this.

Comment: @Rizier123 i think `Ok` means merge the data and `not Ok` means don't merge the data. I am telling based on his desired output.

Comment: @Rizier123, Actually he want to do if the consecutive difference is same as the current index then merge.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. The text says you want to combine the values only if the difference between the keys is `1` or `2` but in the example you combine the values associated with keys `1` and `4` (using `2` as a glue). Last time I checked, `4-1` was still `3`.

Comment: What should be the outcome if the array keys are not in ascending order. F.e., if the keys are `1`, `9`, `2`, `12`, `4`?

Comment: @Anz, Make it a little bit clear what you really want to do???

Comment: Okay, sorry I have made a false analogy to the array ... below I have clarification of the real problem

Answer (score 1):

Try Using

```
$yourarray =array(
                 '1' => array(
                          'a' => 'value 1a'
                        ),
                 '2' => array(
                          'b' => 'value 2b'
                        ),
                 '4' => array(
                          'c' => 'value 4a'
                        ),
                 '9' => array(
                          'd' => 'value 9c'
                        ),
                 '12' => array(
                          'e' => 'value 12e'
                        )
                );

$previousKey = null;

$arraykey_to_merge = null;

$madearray = array();

ksort($yourarray);//no need for current scenario.... 

foreach($yourarray as $key => $newarray)
{
    if($previousKey == null)
    {
        $madearray[$key] = $newarray;
        $previousKey = $key;
        continue;
    }

    $difference = (int)$key - (int)$previousKey;

    if( $difference <= 2 )
    {
        if($arraykey_to_merge == NULL)
        {
            if(!isset($madearray[$key]) || $madearray[$key] == NULL)
            {
                $arraykey_to_merge = $previousKey;
            }
            $madearray[$previousKey] = array_merge($madearray[$previousKey] , $newarray);
            $previousKey = $key;
        }
        else
        {
            $madearray[$arraykey_to_merge] = array_merge($madearray[$arraykey_to_merge] , $newarray);                   
            $arraykey_to_merge = $previousKey;
            $previousKey = $key;
        }

        continue;
    }   
    $madearray[$key] = $newarray;
    $previousKey = $key;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($madearray);
echo "</pre>";
die();
```

Its mess but it will do the job for you... :)

Comment: If you don't start by [sorting the array keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), everything else is in vain.

Comment: @axiac Thanks for your suggestion what `ksort()` will do here ? explain a bit please.....

Comment: Your code assumes the array keys are already sorted ascending. This is probably because this is how they are in the example posted in the question. I would start the code by calling `ksort()` just to make sure the keys really are sorted. Otherwise the code will fail. On a second thought, if the items come already sorted (from the database, f.e.) or they must be processed using their current order then the call to `ksort()` won't help.

Comment: @axiac edit my answer if you think it can be improved :)

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Thanks very much for your suggestion. it works fine, but it still appears there notice and warning when applied to my application..

Comment: @Praveen Notice: Undefined offset: 464,  array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array at $madearray[$arraykey_to_merge] = array_merge($madearray[$arraykey_to_merge] , $newarray); 
but, many thanks for your suggestion and your contribution in solving my problem..work fine in my application...thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that matches the request to combine only the values corresponding to keys whose difference is only `1` or `2`:

```
// Compute the outcome in $results
$result  = array();
// Remember the last key we updated in $results
$lastKey = NULL;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    if (! isset($lastKey)) {
        // No $lastKey; this is the first item of $array1
        // Copy item directly to $results
        $result[$key] = $item;
        $lastKey = $key;
    } elseif ($key - $lastKey <= 2) {
        // Difference is 1 or 2 (given the keys are sorted ascending)
        // Merge item into the previous one
        $result[$lastKey] = array_merge($result[$lastKey], $item);
    } else {
        // Difference is bigger; won't merge. Create a new item in $results
        $result[$key] = $item;
        $lastKey = $key;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

As I remarked in a comment, your expected output doesn't match the request to combine the values that corresponds to keys whose difference is `1` or `2`. It combines all consecutive values as long as the key doesn't increase with more than `2` from one item to the next.

The following code does the combinations using this rule (combine any number of consecutive values as long as the key does not increase with more than `2` from one item to the next):

```
$result  = array();
$lastKey = NULL;
$prevKey = NULL;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    if (! isset($lastKey)) {
        // This is the first item in $result; there is no other item to merge into
        $result[$key] = $item;
        $lastKey = $key;
    } elseif ($key - $prevKey <= 2) {  // Compare with previous element in $array
        // Merge into the last item created in $results
        $result[$lastKey] = array_merge($result[$lastKey], $item);
    } else {
        // Cannot merge, create a new item
        $result[$key] = $item;
        $lastKey = $key;
    }
    $prevKey = $key;
}
```

#### Remark

It is not mentioned in the question if the list is always sorted by keys (because this is how the data comes from the database, f.e.) or the current order of the keys is correct and must not be changed.

If the keys are not guaranteed to be in ascending order but they must be processed in ascending order then a call to [`ksort($array1)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) must be placed in front of the `foreach()` loop in order to get the expected outcome.

#### Remark #2

The code can be written even more compact (it looks bigger in the listing below because it is stuffed with comments) by merging the conditions in order to combine the two blocks of identical assignments in the `if` statements (the first one and the third one):

```
// Compute the outcome in $results
$result  = array();
// Remember the last key of $results; we need to merge new items into it
$lastKey = NULL;
// Remember the previous key of $array1; we compare the current key with it
$prevKey = NULL;
// Process $array1, one item at a time
foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    // Compare with the previous item if there is a previous item
    // (i.e. skip the comparison on the first iteration)
    if (isset($prevKey) && ($key - $prevKey <= 2)) {
        // Merge into the previous group
        $result[$lastKey] = array_merge($result[$lastKey], $item);
    } else {
        // This is the first item (! isset($prevKey)) or ...
        // ... the difference of keys is larger than 2 (! ($key - $prevKey <= 2))
        // Do not merge; copy to the results
        $result[$key] = $item;
        $lastKey = $key;
    }
    // Remember $key; it will be the previous key on the next iteration
    $prevKey = $key;
}
```

Comment: it work fine..Thanks for your help, I like your code looks more simple and I will try to apply in my application...thanks